# asp.net request time out while not join domain

Tags: asp.net, iis, windows-server

I uploaded my project to windows server 2008.

The project generates some reports which takes more than 2 minutes.( sometimes 4 to 5 minutes)

The problem is when user who doesn't join domain, there is error request timeout.

The cause of error is the the time taken to generate the report.
Here is the screenshot of the error:

[IMG]http://i47.tinypic.com/34i5vd0.png[/IMG]

here the code

```
Protected Sub btnOSA_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnOSA.Click
        Dim apps As New MyApps
        Dim connsql As New SqlCommand
        apps.OpenConnection()

        connsql.Connection = apps.oConn
        connsql.CommandTimeout = 3600
        connsql.CommandText = "GetWeeklyPICDetail @pmon, @pyear"
        connsql.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pmon", SqlDbType.Int)
        connsql.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pyear", SqlDbType.Int)
        connsql.Parameters("@pmon").Value = cmbMonthParam.Value
        connsql.Parameters("@pyear").Value = cmbYearParam.Value


        connsql.ExecuteNonQuery()

        apps.CloseConnection()

        btnExportSPC.Visible = True

    End Sub
```

here my web.config line

```
<appSettings>
    <add key="connStr" value="Data Source=xxx;initial catalog=xxx;user ID=sa;Password=password;Connection Timeout=3600;   "/>
  </appSettings>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="connStr" connectionString="Data Source=xxx;Initial Catalog=xxx;User ID=sa;Password=password;Timeout=3600" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
```

Comment: can you show us your codes ?

Answer (score 0):

You should increase time out configuration.

In your web config define following section

`<httpRuntime executionTimeout="800" />`

Parameter defined in seconds.

If it does not help in you Asp.Net on Page Load add this line

// Increase session timout to 8 minutes
Session.Timout = 8;